# Recovery user email from Facebook using Spring Social on Android

Tags: android, spring, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm using a sample of a Android application that uses Spring Social to make the user login. I'm using Spring-social and Spring-social-facebook 1.0.3. The sample is published on [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-android-samples/tree/master/spring-android-facebook-client). I'm trying to get the user email from Facebook, but always I get a empty value. I am just getting the name and id.

My connect_settings.xml to make the connections and ask the permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="facebook_app_id"> MY ID </string>
    <string name="facebook_app_secret"> MY SECRET </string>
    <string name="facebook_oauth_callback_url">https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html</string>
    <string name="facebook_scope">"user_about_me,email"</string>
</resources>
```

I get the data on FacebookProfileListAdapter.java

```
        case 0:
            item[0] = "Id";
            item[1] = String.valueOf(facebookProfile.getId());
            break;
        case 1:
            item[0] = "Name";
            item[1] = facebookProfile.getName();
            break;
        case 2:
            item[0] = "Email";
            item[1] = facebookProfile.getEmail();
            break;
```

I logged with my user account, and just retrieved my name and my ID.
I've no idea how to get the user's email.

Comment: You need to ask for the email address field in your request

Comment: <string name="facebook_scope">"user_about_me,email"</string> ?

Comment: Those are which permissions you want to request from the user. Not which fields you request in the request

Comment: Solved. Needs to migrate the libs (social core, social facebook, jackson) to lastest version